# Failed to load external entity Error While reading SOAP file in Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

I am getting this error while doing Parse XML. 
OSError: Error reading file 'CommandResponseError.xml': failed to load external entity "CommandResponseError.xml"

My Code ::

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation    Suite description
Library  XML

*** Variables ***
${InputPath}                     ${CURDIR}\\Input
${CommandResponseErrorXML}       CommandResponseError.xml

*** Test Cases ***
Construct Error Code XML To PUSH
    [Documentation]  This KW is used to construct Error XML File
    [Tags]    XML read
     ${XMLNodes}=   Parse XML   ${CommandResponseErrorXML}
```

I am using XML Library to parse xml.

Here is the XML file.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Header/>
    <soap:Body>
        <SendTOPMessages xmlns="http://schemas.turtletech.com/TS2/">
            <messages>
                <RFTOPCommand xmlns="http://schemas.turtletech.com/TS2/">
                    <MessageId>#MessageId</MessageId>
                    <ReceivedTime>1496632500</ReceivedTime>
                    <TOPAddress>#RFCollectorIdentifier</TOPAddress>
                    <LocalWANAddress>0</LocalWANAddress>
                    <LocalLANAddress>4278124157</LocalLANAddress>
                    <RemoteWANAddress>#RemoteWANAddress</RemoteWANAddress>
                    <RemoteLANAddress>#SerialNumber</RemoteLANAddress>
                    <Priority>1</Priority>
                    <TimeToLive>298</TimeToLive>
                    <Mood>0</Mood>
                    <ReturnReceipt>0</ReturnReceipt>
                    <MaxHops>252</MaxHops>
                    <MessageType>4</MessageType>
                    <MessagePayload>#Payload</MessagePayload>
                </RFTOPCommand>
            </messages>
        </SendTOPMessages>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Are you certain this code gives that exact error? I am able to run your code against this data with robot 2.9 and 3.0.4 with both python 2.7 and 3.5.2. It appears you're using windows, though I'm using linux.

Comment: I'm testing on windows 10 Robot Framework 3.0.4 (Python 2.7.13 ) it's working fine with your code .

Comment: Ahh !! I got the point I have kept my xml file in Input Folder and i am trying to access from there. If i keep at same file level code is working. Not sure why its throwing if file is in another directory.

Answer (score 2):

In your code example:

```
${XMLNodes}=   Parse XML   ${CommandResponseErrorXML}
```

your referring to `${CommandResponseErrorXML}` which in turn refers to:

```
${CommandResponseErrorXML}       CommandResponseError.xml.
```

This will work if the Robot file and `CommandResponseError.xml` are in the same folder. Change it to:

```
${InputPath}                     ${CURDIR}/Input
${CommandResponseErrorXML}       ${InputPath}/CommandResponseError.xml
```

and you will add the InputPath to create the full path to the Root/Input/file.xml.

Note: the single forward slash works on both Unix and Windows. In my view it's preferred over and escaped backslash. Even if only for readability reasons.